# ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {} missing required keys: [:id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

The error is:

`ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches 
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>#<User id: 21, name: "Test", email: "test@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$UE170rpnHsdnTOMfBC190uiHQ/ygmLkRxfsTaRMBBT/...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2015-09-14 04:11:22", last_sign_in_at: "2015-09-14 04:11:22", current_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:128.250.1.8/255.255.255.255>, last_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:128.250.1.8/255.255.255.255>, created_at: "2015-09-14 04:11:22", updated_at: "2015-09-14 04:11:22">} missing required keys: [:id]):`

I think the problem is in the html code:

```
 <%= link_to 'Profile', user_path(current_user) %>

 <%= link_to 'Upload Meter Data', user_path(current_user) %>
```

But it works correctly in local. The problem only happened in heroku.

My `route.rb`:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
  get 'users/import' => 'users#upload_nem12'
  post 'users/import' => 'users#import_nem12'
  # user's show page
  # get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'   
  resources :users, only: [:show],  constraints: { id: /\d/ }
  get 'users/profile' => 'users#show'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :users, only: [:show],  constraints: { id: /\d/ }
```

try this:

```
/\d/ change to /\d+/
```